# What is limitations of saving data on Android/data/package-name?

Tags: java, android, android-external-storage

Is there a space limit for saving app data in Android/data/data/your_package/ path for any application? for example, if Primary External Storage has 3G free,could I (android developer) save 3G data on this folder?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no limit for storing app files in android (but maybe there is a little less space free than it seems).

However you should remember, that there is a limit for published in Google Play '.apk' file size (50mb or 100mb for different Google Play versions), but you can use up to two APK expansion files for every '.apk' file up to 2GB each.

P.S. Keep in mind that External Data Storage isn't the same as Internal Data Storage. EDS is your SD card and unless you have a permission etc. to use it in your app you won't be able to store files there. Default place for app files is IDS, internal android device memory.